# Mount kubernetes volume in docker container without erasing the container's data

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, mounted-volumes

I'm using the [kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) to setup a pipeline on jenkins to compile some code.

**MY GOAL:**
In this pipeline, I'm trying to access some data from a docker container to use it as a cache in a second on (as shown below).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cache-test
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: cache-container
    image: cache:latest
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /cache
    command: 
      - cat


  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: 
      - cat
```

**PROBLEM:**
My issue is that when I mount my `shared-folder` in `/cache` directly, all my data get erased (overwritten).
**WORK AROUND:**
One work around would be to to create an intermediate directory where I can copy my data:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cache-test
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: cache-container
    image: cache:latest
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /shared-folder
    command: 
      - cat


  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: 
      - cat
```

And the in my Jenkins pipeline add this step:

```
          container('cache-container') {
                sh """#!/usr/bin/env bash
                set -exu
                cp -r /cache/* /shared-folder
                """
              } // container
```

**QUESTION:**
Is there a way to avoid this copy step? Maybe a kubernetes volume setup that doesn't overwrite what's in the container? 
I went through the documentation couple times without finding anything..

Comment: And you have read documentation from K8s on persistent storage?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

Comment: This behavior is the same as normal Linux **mount**(8).  What behavior do you expect if you start three different pods all mounting the same shared volume, but their initial content is all different?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a container as a cache without copying data to a volume shared with other containers. But you probably shouldn't anyway.

You probably want to move your cache out of the container and make it a PersistentVolume. PersistentVolumeClaims can **claim** PV and then pods can mount these PVCs.

The problem with PVs, no matter static or dynamic they are - they won't be `Available` for PVCs when previously locking PVC was deleted. They will stuck in `Released` state. Kubernetes doesn't do it automatically for a reason - workloads aren't supposed to have access to data from other workloads. For when they do - the idiomatic Kubernetes way to do it is StatefulSets, so Kubernetes guarantees that only the replicas of the same workload may claim the old data. Unfortunately it's just doesn't work for a build caches.

I wrote two simple controllers - automatic PV releaser (that would find and make `Released` PVs `Available` again for new PVCs) and dynamic PVC provisioner (for Jenkins Kubernetes plugin specifically - so you can define a PVC as annotation on a Pod). Check it out here https://github.com/plumber-cd/kubernetes-dynamic-reclaimable-pvc-controllers. There is a full `Jenkinsfile` example here https://github.com/plumber-cd/kubernetes-dynamic-reclaimable-pvc-controllers/tree/main/examples/jenkins-kubernetes-plugin-with-build-cache.